# Does killing Shanalotte aka. The Emerald Herald change the rest of the game?

Tags: dark-souls-2

[When killed Shanalotte drops the Aged Feather](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_Herald#Strategy), and you can no longer use her services (unless revived, but it's unclear whether this is even possible). Are there any non-obvious differences to the rest of the game, especially lore-related, like changed dialogue, locations or items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from her being dead and thus unable to appear in other locations, no. You can [use her services at her grave](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/emerald-herald) by paying some souls.

Comment: Do you know what happens with the feather (permanent homeward bone) that she gives near endgame?

Comment: She drops it on death if killed before she gives it to you.

Comment: This is, by far, the absolute worst way of acquiring the Aged Feather.  It's much cheaper for you to just buy homeward bones than to kill her.  You only need to level up 3-4 times and the revival cost will already exceed your Homeward Bone cost.  My latest play-through I only used 3 homeward bones before I got the feather!